# New user is a diamond mod?

Tags: discussion, moderators, new-users

While working the first posts review queue, I was presented with [this first answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/31600/6986) by a new user. While everything seemed fine at first glance, I noticed the user under review, [Pops](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/133/pops), is a brand new user and a diamond moderator. Pops also appears to be a diamond mod on several other sites within the Stack Exchange community.

Maybe I missed something, but I didn't think we held elections recently for new moderators here on Worldbuilding. Do diamond mods keep their status across sites, or is there something fishy going on here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm a Community Manager (i.e. a Stack Exchange employee), so I have diamonds everywhere. I just look new because I've never really interacted with this particular site before. Nothing happened with your elections (or anything else), I just decided to poke my head out and see why everyone was saying this site is so awesome!

To explicitly answer your last question, diamond mods typically hold office on just one site. There are a few non-employees with diamonds on multiple sites, but they were elected or appointed to each site individually and independently.

Comment: I don't know. You look more like a mythical monkey king than my fellow employee. What are you hiding under that mask?

Comment: @JonEricson that comment... is not going to age well.

Comment: Welcome to [my world](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270851/1438).

Comment: We had a user become a moderator [out of the blue](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1720/6986) a while ago, so I just wanted to make sure. Thanks for popping in! (pun intended)

Comment: Pun intended, huh? Yeah, I think I'm going to like it here.

Comment: Hey, Pops is here!  Welcome to Worldbuilding!

Comment: _Frosted Monkey Pops; they're magically delicious!_

Comment: @TimPost That's horrifying. And I can't imagine how to build a world where it's not.

Comment: @Pops You're in the right place to ask that question :D

Comment: Far too many diamonds in this comment thread.

Comment: @Pops Easy: "monkeys" are humanoid-shaped sweet fruits akin to bananas. Put 'em on sticks, dip in chocolate, sprinkle with a little magic a la Willy Wonka, and that jingle slogan becomes a comment about flavor.

Comment: I think @JonEricson 's comment adds to the intrigue. I'm interested to learn your connection to [Sun Wukong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Wukong)

Comment: @Erik I think I was wearing a Sun Wukong mask at the time Jon's comment was written; see the end of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271127/).

Comment: @Pops brilliant that makes perfect sense